# ScrollView doesn't align (leading nor trailing)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following view:

[image]

Code:

```
HStack {
    Text("Blockchains connected:")
    
    Spacer()
    
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            Text("e3f")
    } .frame(minWidth: 22, maxWidth: 100, alignment: .trailing)
}
```

The part that you see on the image highlighted with a square around the text `e3f` is the scrollview code above.

How can I move that thing all the way to the right? I've tried placing multiples HStacks with `Spacer()`, VStack with alignment `.leading` and nothing...

Any suggestion?

Comment: why do you use a `ScrollView`? Is it a long code, that should show its "end"?

Comment: yes, there are going to be some images there of about 20x20, I want them trailing aligned @ChrisR

Comment: and why do they have to be scrollable?

Comment: what happens if you put 20 images 20x20 in `HStack` in that box highlighted? It breaks the layout and everything right? That's why it needs to be Scrollview and horizontal @ChrisR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scrolls to the trailing end of the scrollview, but **only** if the content is wider than the scrollview frame ... so you might have to "pad" some empty images in front if you have too few.

```
struct ContentView: View {
            
    let codes = "e3f e3f e3f e3f e3f e3f e3f e3f"
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Blockchains connected:")
                .font(.callout)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
            Spacer()
            
            ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    Text(codes)
                        .id(1)
                        .onAppear {
                            scrollProxy.scrollTo(1, anchor: .trailing)
                        }
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 100)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(.blue)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work :\  leave only 1 `e3f` and see if it aligns to the right

Comment: as I wrote ... you have to pad then by using "____________ e3f" (_ = space)

Comment: I can’t believe there isn’t a native way to align this…  If I have to resort to a trick I can just count the # of images and if it's <= 2 use a HStack, but I didn't want to use that.

Comment: the logic is: If the content of a ScollView is fitting without scrolling, then you can't scroll. ––– You could switch between a regular view and a scrollview depending on your nr of images. Are the images always 20x20px ?

Comment: yep always the same size, I have it working counting the images switching between scrollview and hstack, I just want to see if someone knows a native solution to align this instead of resorting to this trick